# Display query result with raw html and ruby inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For displaying html escaping you can do:

```
<%= raw @main_post.description %>
```

Is it possible to to execute ruby/rails code that is stored inside @main_post.description ? For example a global variable (like MyApp::Application::PHONE_NUMBER) or a Date.today command.

How the command should be stored inside the query and how it will be displayed on the view?

Comment: that's basically the role of Proc or lambdas

Answer (score 2):

First of all, doing so is **extremely** dangerous, if the data in the the database can be edited by anyone but you... that would give any poster programmatic control, which is not so much a security hole as a complete lack of security.

A couple of ways to do it though:   A simple string sent to an object:

```
<%= @custom_object.send(@post.code_field) %>
```

If you define a custom class that has a limited number of methods, this could trigger them. (You could even validate the field to limit the security exposure)

To execute a completely arbitrary bit of code, use [Kernel#eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001390)

```
<%= eval @post.code_field %>
```

OTOH, if your goal is to simply add a bit of dynamic content to the post, how about setting up some template tags in the post and then substituting them?

```
@post.description = "Here's the date: {{date}}"
```

...

```
<%= @post.description.gsub('{{date}}', Date.today)
```

Comment: Nice approach the gsub :). It needs Date.today.to_s but it works. In either case I am still wondering how it should be done the above, I know the eval but I don't know how I should store it inside the query to work and show raw html also.

Comment: Showing raw html .. you mean show the tags?  Or render it so that it formats?    In rails 3, text has to be marked as html_safe to format...   google for rails html_safe or the raw function

Comment: I'd like to see an example of what the query string (@main_post.description) should return so it will show the correct result of the ruby code. I tried many alternatives with eval but it didn't work, it is showing as plain text (for example I see it as <%= date.today %> instead of the current date).

Comment: I don't know what I should put inside the field. Erb code or something else? I want to display html tags, strings and parse some ruby which is inside the field, my problem is I don't know how I should put the ruby code. Should I use <%= %> or should I try something different like #{Date.today} ? I tried some variations but it didn't work.